# First Name and Last Name not allowing to use Latin letter

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation, name

I am Using Magento 1.9.1

Gómez 
nº

these letters are not allowing in my customer form. please help.

Comment: Which validation class you have used in input box?

Comment: validate-alphanum-with-spaces

Answer (score 0):

go to `js/prototype/validation.js` you can only allowed the character for that and spaces

```
['validate-alphanum-with-spaces', 'Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.', function(v) {
   return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)
            }],
```

**solution** 
this expression you need for latin test and working

```
['validate-alphanum-with-spaces-with-latin', 'Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.', function(v) {
                        return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)

     }],
```

Comment: now, what i have to do ? need to the function in validation js?

Comment: i need to update the function , and also have to change the class name in the form too ? sir !!

Comment: "validate-alphanum-with-spaces " this is the name of the class sir?

Comment: actually I have the same function on Line 488. its doesnot support latin letter.

Comment: Is there any way to add the function and edit the function to allow the latin letters? without remove the class name?

Comment: its only accept group of the letters like "nºaser" But not accept by single letter "nº" and "adetó" this to not working!

Comment: This js not working!!

Comment: This too not working

Comment: Qaisar . This is not working !!!

Comment: which one your telling ?
1) change for single letter 
2) this expression you need for latin not test

Comment: Actually 
I edit the function not declaring the new one. i have lot name field form with same validation class. so here my code

Comment: then add the return code only

Comment: ['validate-alphanum-with-spaces', 'Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.', function(v) {
                    //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A.......\uFFDA-\uFFDC a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(v)
            }],

Comment: remove `//` before return. you comment the code

Comment: yeah i did it. but nor working

Comment: //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v)

comes new line

['validate-alphanum-with-spaces', 'Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.', function(v) { //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/.test(v) return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-‌​\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037‌​D\u0386\u0388-\u038A.......\uFFDA-\uFFDC a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(v) }],

Comment: yes. i pasted the updated your return values to my validation js

Comment: No getting the error in console.

but Having This Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or spaces only in this field.

Comment: i comment the default line. not the your return values returning  next line

Comment: okay thanks. unfortunately Your Answer not helped  me sorry it.!!

Comment: @Crock updated the answer one last time and test too and works for me.

Comment: sorry this is too. havenot work for me.. i dont know, why your tested answers not work for me.. even i was cleared the cache and index. too

Comment: tested on my local magento  it wokring with `Gómez` and `ó`